# Moment unable to convert in different timezone

Tags: javascript, momentjs

My server is returning me dates in UTC and I want to convert them to the timezone of the server (even if the customer browser is in a different timezone !)

Here is one example, my server is in Europe/Berlin.

```js
var dateAsString = '2022-04-11T22:00:00.000Z'; // 2022-04-12 00:00:00 in Europe/Berlin
var utcDate = moment.utc(dateAsString);
console.log(utcDate.format());
var serverTzDate = utcDate.clone().tz('Europe/Berlin');
console.log(serverTzDate.format());
console.log(serverTzDate.format());

var test = moment.utc('2022-04-11T22:00:00.000Z').tz('Europe/Berlin').format();
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.34/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>
```

If my browser is in the Europe/Berlin timezone the output is correct:

```
2022-04-11T22:00:00Z
2022-04-12T00:00:00+02:00
2022-04-12T00:00:00+02:00
```

But if I change my timezone (for my example I took Pacific/Niue), then the result is totally wrong, I suppose moment is doing something with the timezone of the browser but how to avoid this ? Here is the output:

```
2022-04-11T09:00:00Z
2022-04-11T11:00:00+02:00
2022-04-11T11:00:00+02:00
```

**I need to have the date in the timezone of the server and not in the timezone of the browser**

With another timezone: Pacific/Kiritimati (-840)

```
2022-04-12T10:00:00Z // Wanted 2022-04-11T22:00:00Z (UTC Date as entered)
2022-04-12T12:00:00+02:00 // Wanted 2022-04-12T00:00:00Z (Converted in Europe/Berlin)
2022-04-12T12:00:00+02:00 // Wanted 2022-04-12T00:00:00Z (Converted in Europe/Berlin)
2022-04-12T12:00:00+02:00 // Wanted 2022-04-12T00:00:00Z (Converted in Europe/Berlin)
```

Again all the dates are wrong, moment seems not able to parse my date as an UTC date ? It apply the timezone offset of the browser even if I'm using the `utc` method

Comment: can you access the time zone of the server though?

Comment: I have the id of the timezone, like "Europe/Berlin" for ex

Comment: Can you include the code you are using for "Pacific/Niue"

Comment: Exactly the same, I just change the timezone of my browser !

Comment: @Spialdor What do you mean by *“I just change the timezone of my browser”*? Most browsers use the system timezone. Do you mean that you changed your system timezone? Are you dynamically fetching `'Europe/Berlin'` from the browser and then passing it to `tz()`? If so, why not pass `'Europe/Berlin'` as a literal?

Comment: `'Europe/Berlin'` is a "fixed" string, I receive it from my server that tells my we want date in this timezone. But now my browser is in `Pacific/Niue` timezone, I just use the chrome utilities to change the timezone.
So the thing is that, my server returns me dates in UTC but tells me we want to display them in `'Europe/Berlin'`, so I just want to convert the dates I receive to `'Europe/Berlin'`, but if the browser timezone is different then nothings works for me and the dates are far from what is expected

Answer (score 0):

```
moment.utc('2022-04-11T22:00:00.000Z').tz('Europe/Berlin').format()
```

please check this document. https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/

below is my code result,  whatever timezone you changed, the result is `'2022-04-12T00:00:00+02:00'`
[image]

Comment: OP had a problem with the Pacific/Niue timezone! Could you explain what OP got wrong?

Comment: I added your code in my snippet, still returning "2022-04-11T11:00:00+02:00" (which is wrong !) if my browser is in Pacific/Niue timezone

Comment: I updated my comment and upload the result screenshot.